# Position elements relative to containers (and containers relative to bigger containers) using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there thanks for reading this post.

I had some container divs which hold some element divs, yet I also have a wrapper that wrap all the container divs. How should I ret the css style so that an element's position is relative to a container, a container's position is relative to a bigger container, and the bigger container's position is relative to the ultimate container (i.e. wrapper)?

Do I need javascript for this?

Thans you!!

Comment: Check out the semantics of [position: relative](http://dochub.io/#css/position)

Comment: my problem is, when i have a container and some elements inside - using css position is fine. but if i have another container which contains the small container, since the smaller container is set as relative, I cannot set it as absolute so that it becomes relative to the larger container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the main container to have a position:relative and the child containers to be position:absolute. If you need to put more containers inside the child ones you can use position:absolute on them also.

eg:

```
.wrapper{position:relative;}
.big-container{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.containerOne{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.containerTwo{position:absolute:top:0;left:0;}
```

Comment: He can use both `relative` and `absolute` positioning on any of the parent or child containers, other than that, your response is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I got it right now. In fact I was doing what you propose here earlier on. I set the wrapper as relative and all others as absolute but it didn't work. Now I test it again without changing anything and it works. I'm using Dreamweaver 6 by the way; could it be because of some loading problems with this software? In fact I can remember running into similar trouble, i.e. not ok in the morning, suddenly ok at night.